# Are variables in a header file global scope?

Tags: c++, header, enums

Say I have a header file to store an enum:

my_enum.h:

```
#ifndef my_enum_h
#define my_enum_h
enum my_enum {ONE, TWO};
#endif
```

Then I include this header file in the files `game.h` and `game.cc`. Finally, I include `game.h` in `main.cc`.

I can now use ONE and TWO in `main.cc`. Is it normal to have these variables globally defined?

Comment: I don't understand. Just comment this line out from the file.

Comment: As `main.cc` `include`s `game.h`, which `include`s `my_enum.h` - this is normal (technically, an `include` directive is replaced by the content of the file, being included). If you want to hide the `enum`, define it in the source file, can't you? Or it's used in the header file, too?

Comment: Just comment out all these lines, if you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include game.h in main.cc, because game.h already includes my_enum.h, it can be accessed from files who include game.h, aswell as including my_enum.h

Solution 1:
Remove "#include my_enum.h" from your code, as it doesn't seem as if it needed

Solution 2:
Maybe change the name of the enum/the values inside

Comment: Thank you! Although I am wiser and brighter now, this helped me back then. I was really looking for encapsulating the `enum` in a `namespace` like so: `namespace my_enum { enum e {ONE, TWO}; };`

Answer (score 0):

If you include a header in your implementation file. It is the same as writing the exact code of header file in your implementation file.

Hence this `enum` declaration gets included in your `game.h` and subsequently in your `main.cc`.

If you want to remove it, you will have to remove it from the header file and declare it locally wherever you want to use it.